# symfony2 router service dependency

Tags: symfony, service

I have a service in BITGoogleBundle thats depend on router service to generate the callback route specific:

```
BIT\GoogleBundle\Google\GoogleClient::setUp
```

If i call this method in the constructor i get this error:

```
ServiceCircularReferenceException: Circular reference detected for service 
"security.context", path: "profiler_listener -> profiler -> security.context -> 
security.authentication.manager -> bit_google.client -> routing.loader -> 
assetic.asset_manager -> twig".
```

But if i call it as a normal function from other services it works just fine.

What its the approach here to avoid this error?

**EDIT:**

`google.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>

<container xmlns="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xsi:schemaLocation="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services/services-1.0.xsd">
    <services>
        <service id="bit_google.client" class="%bit_google.client.class%">
            <argument type="collection">
                <argument key="app_name">%bit_google.app_name%</argument>
                <argument key="client_id">%bit_google.client_id%</argument>
                <argument key="client_secret">%bit_google.client_secret%</argument>
                <argument key="simple_api_access">%bit_google.simple_api_access%</argument>
                <argument key="state">%bit_google.state%</argument>
                <argument key="access_type">%bit_google.access_type%</argument>
                <argument key="scopes">%bit_google.scopes%</argument>
                <argument key="approval_prompt">%bit_google.approval_prompt%</argument>
                <argument key="callback_route">%bit_google.callback_route%</argument>
            </argument>
            <argument type="service" id="session"/>
            <argument type="service" id="router"/>
        </service>
        <service id="bit_google.user" class="%bit_google.user.class%">
            <argument type="service" id="bit_google.client"/>
        </service>
        <service id="bit_google.contact" class="%bit_google.contact.class%">
            <argument type="service" id="bit_google.client"/>
        </service>
        <service id="bit_google.url" class="%bit_google.url.class%">
            <argument type="service" id="bit_google.client"/>
        </service>
        <service id="bit_google.twig" class="%bit_google.twig.class%">
            <argument type="service" id="service_container"/>
            <argument type="service" id="bit_google.client"/>
            <tag name="twig.extension"/>
        </service>
    </services>
</container>
```

`GoogleClient.php`

```
/*
 * This file is part of the BITGoogleBundle package.
 *
 * (c) bitgandtter <http://bitgandtter.github.com/>
 *
 * For the full copyright and license information, please view the LICENSE
 * file that was distributed with this source code.
 */
namespace BIT\GoogleBundle\Google;

use Google_Client;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Router;

/**
 * Implements Symfony2 service for Google_Client.
 */
class GoogleClient extends Google_Client
{

    const PREFIX = '_bit_google_';
    protected static $supportedKeys = array('access_token', 'user_id');
    private $config;
    private $session;
    private $router;
    private $prefix;

    public function __construct(array $config, Session $session, Router $router, $prefix = self::PREFIX)
    {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->config = $config;
        $this->session = $session;
        $this->router = $router;
        $this->prefix = $prefix;

        $this->setUp();
    }

    public function setup()
    {
        $this->setApplicationName($this->config ["app_name"]);
        $this->setClientId($this->config ["client_id"]);
        $this->setClientSecret($this->config ["client_secret"]);

        $this->setState($this->config ["state"]);
        $this->setAccessType($this->config ["access_type"]);
        $this->setApprovalPrompt($this->config ["approval_prompt"]);

        if ($this->config ["simple_api_access"]) {
            $this->setDeveloperKey($this->config ["simple_api_access"]);
        }

        $scopes = array();
        $scopes[] = "openid";

        if ($this->config ["scopes"]["profile"]) {
            $scopes[] = "profile";
            $scopes[] = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login";
            $scopes[] = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me";
        }

        if ($this->config ["scopes"]["email"]) {
            $scopes[] = "email";
            $scopes[] = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.profile.emails.read";
        }

        if ($this->config ["scopes"]["contact"]) {
            $scopes[] = "https://www.google.com/m8/feeds";
        }

        $this->requestedScopes = $scopes;

        $this->setRedirectUri($this->router->generate($this->config ["callback_route"], array(), Router::ABSOLUTE_URL));

        $this->getAccessToken();
    }

    public function getAccessToken()
    {
        parent::setAccessToken($this->getPersistentData('access_token'), null);
        return parent::getAccessToken();
    }

    /**
     * Get the data for $key
     *
     * @param string $key     The key of the data to retrieve
     * @param null   $default The default value to return if $key is not found
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getPersistentData($key, $default = null)
    {
        $this->checkSupportedKeys($key);
        return $this->session->get($this->constructSessionVariableName($key), $default);
    }

    private function constructSessionVariableName($key)
    {
        return $this->prefix . implode('_', array('g', $this->config ["client_id"], $key));
    }

    /**
     * Clear the data with $key from the persistent storage
     *
     * @param string $key
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function clearPersistentData($key)
    {
        $this->checkSupportedKeys($key);
        $this->session->remove($this->constructSessionVariableName($key));
    }

    private function checkSupportedKeys($key)
    {
        if (!in_array($key, self::$supportedKeys)) {
            throw new \Google_Exception('Unsupported key passed to getPersistentData.');
        }
    }

    /**
     * Clear all data from the persistent storage
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function clearAllPersistentData()
    {
        foreach ($this->session->all() as $k => $v) {
            if (0 !== strpos($k, $this->prefix)) {
                continue;
            }

            $this->session->remove($k);
        }
    }

    public function setAccessToken($accessToken)
    {
        parent::setAccessToken($accessToken);
        $this->setPersistentData('access_token', $accessToken);
    }

    /**
     * Stores the given ($key, $value) pair, so that future calls to
     * getPersistentData($key) return $value.
     * This call may be in another request.
     *
     * @param string $key
     * @param array  $value
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function setPersistentData($key, $value)
    {
        $this->checkSupportedKeys($key);
        $this->session->set($this->constructSessionVariableName($key), $value);
    }

}
```

All of that its part of a bundle called GoogleBundle in my repos on github, there you cand find all the code, but the above its the one with the problem

Comment: Please, be more specific. How do you call this method? What does your `services.yml` look like? What does the code for this service look like?

Comment: @kix i add more information in the main post

Comment: @bitgandtter Have you solved this?

Comment: yes @RostyslavKinash, the issue was throw when i call it from a twig extension, i solve it moving the functionality, some sort of walk around but, from the version 2.4 of symfony its recommended to use the request_stack service, that way it should solve the issue